# Run two commands at same time and pipe to third command

Tags: command-line

I currently want to run in my terminal cmd1 and cmd2.  I want to pipe these outputs to cmd3, which can take multiple inputs.

I tried

```
cmd1 && cmd2 | cmd3 -i - -i -
```

But this does not accomplish what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To answer your question literally (*"Run two commands at same time and pipe to third command
"*)**

You would need to put at least one of the LHS commands into the shell background using `&`, and group them so that the combined standard output may be redirected ex.

```
{ cmd1 & cmd2; } | cmd3 -i - -i -
```

Note that `&` is different from `&&` (which waits for `cmd1` to exit, then *conditionally* executes `cmd2`).

You could replace the command group `{ ... ; }` with a subshell `( ... )` if you prefer. Since the shell has only one standard output and one standard input stream, this will merge the outputs of `cmd1` and `cmd2`

---

**To answer what you actually seem to want**

To redirect the outputs of two separate commands as two separate input streams in bash, you can use *process substitution*:

```
cmd3 -i <(cmd1) -i <(cmd2)
```

Comment: Will this redirect the pipes or try and merge the pipes to one?